# Unable to redirect to Lazy Loaded module as default route/url on server start up

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Good day folks,

I am having this issue in my Angular 2 application upon server startup (`npm start`).

I redirect the base route or base path to `user/login` which is a Lazy Loaded module but it throws an `Cannot find module` error. This always happens as I've said, during startup and editing the `pathMatch` argument from `'full'` to `'prefix'` and vice versa fixes the error and loads the route without error.

I hope you can help me with this.

Below is the program.

**app/routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const appRoutes:Routes = [
    { path: 'user', loadChildren:  'user/user.module#UserModule'},  
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'user/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

**app/app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app/user/user.routes.ts**

```
import { LoginComponent } from "./login.component";

export const userRoutes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
]
```

**app/user/user.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { userRoutes } from "./user.routes";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login.component";


@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes)
],
declarations: [
    LoginComponent
],
providers: [UserAuthService]
})

export class UserModule {}
```

I hope I've provided enough information about my problem. If not, just let me know. Thank you.

EDIT:

I'm having the same error when I visit `user/login` upon startup.

Comment: Do you have the same error when trying to get directly to the `localhost:port/user` path ? `user/login` is not a defined route.

Comment: @ibenjelloun Yes, I'm having the same error.

Comment: @ibenjelloun `user/login` is defined through the `user` at routes.ts which prepends and translated by angular once it loaded the child routes of the said module.

Comment: You did not export your `RouterModule` in the `UserModule`, right ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun What do you mean by not exporting `RouterModule`?

Comment: Your routing architecture does not really make sense. Why are you lazy loading your UserModule, if it is the module you route to immediately from your root application on initialization? That certainly is not the use case for lazy loading.

Comment: so it seems that there are some people in the community that are experiencing also the same problem not just in startup but generally using the latest angular-cli and still there is no fix to the problem. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `() =>` notation actually worked for me. Below is my code regarding how I fixed it just by editing my routes.ts file

**app/routes.ts**

```
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

export const appRoutes:Routes = [
  { path: 'user', loadChildren: () => UserModule},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},    
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'user/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

Comment: WARNING: This will stop your module from being lazy loaded. Yout should use the answer by [ibenjelloun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195647/181569) if you would like to preserve lazy loading.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:**
Since Angular 8, the way to lazy load modules is using dynamic imports such as:

```js
 export const appRoutes:Routes = [
    { path: 'user', loadChildren:  () => import('path-to-module').then(m => m.UserModule)},  
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

The accepted answer is not the correct way to implement lazyLoading at all.
This should be the routing mechanism:

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
{ path: 'user', loadChildren:  'user/user.module#UserModule'},  
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

]

**user.routes.ts**

```
export const userRoutes = [
 {
path: '',
children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }]
```

}
]

[ibenjelloun's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8945135/ibenjelloun) answer is correct. Since you mentioned somehow it doesn't seem to work for you, I have given an alternative way with child routes.

Comment: Please note that loading lazy modules using a string value is [deprecated since Angular 8](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#loadchildren-string-syntax).
The correct way to lazy load a module is by using the `import()` function:
`loadChildren:  () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your ***user.module.ts*** like this :

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes)
],
declarations: [
    LoginComponent
],
exports: [RouterModule], // Add this line
providers: [UserAuthService]
})

export class UserModule {}
```

And ***routes.ts*** :

```
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
    { path: 'user', loadChildren:  'user/user.module#UserModule'},  
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

Also ***user.routes.ts*** :

```
export const userRoutes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
]
```

Comment: This didn't fixed my concern.

Comment: Are you getting the same error ? Please give some details.
Take a look at this simplest example, you are maybe forgetting other configurations : https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplest-routing-example

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error even I've already followed your answer.

Comment: I'm actually puzzled by the behavior of my application. I've followed the angular docs with this and yet I'm still having the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In case your user has a home component, this trick worked for me :

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const appRoutes:Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full' }
  { path: 'user', loadChildren: () => import('path-to-module').then(m => m.UserModule) }
]
```

**user.routes.ts**

```
export const userRoutes = [{
    path: '', 
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [ {
        path:'',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }, {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }, {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
    }]
   } 
 ]
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved a similar issue using  after see a project on github from SaranyaRagupathi the repository its the book-store

Comment: you need to share link to make it informative and clear