# Setting the default route with Angular lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm lazy loading modules with Angular, but if I navigate to the URL without providing a route path, e.g. `http://localhost:4200` it loads my `about.module` when I'd expect the `home.module` to be loaded. Eagerly loading the modules works as expected.

Each module has a `*-routing.module`:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
/* ... */

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'page-not-found'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes
      /* ... */
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

/* ... */
```

**home-routing.module.ts**

```
/* ... */

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* ... */
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

/* ... */
```

**about-routing.module.ts**

```
/* ... */

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AboutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'About'
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* ... */
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

/* ... */
```

Other solutions I have tried and are for an older version of Angular don't seem to work:

- [Unable to redirect to Lazy Loaded module as default route/url on server start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194645/unable-to-redirect-to-lazy-loaded-module-as-default-route-url-on-server-start-up/49195647#49195647)

I'm working with Angular 8+ in this case.

Comment: Your code should work... are you sure you have saved all your files, and your project was recompiled? To be safe, do a `ctrl + c` and `ng serve` again

Comment: @Riv Positive, I did refactor to just eagerly load the modules to make sure, and that worked fine. Not sure what I'm missing here with lazy loading!

Comment: You should not lazy load your default route